# In Clojure, reading a file which is specified at the command prompt

Tags: clojure, readfile

I am a newbie to Clojure and I am trying to read a file which should be specified at the command line.

When I try the following, giving the file name at REPL, it is working

```
(ns testpj.core
   (:require [clojure.java.io :as io]))

  (defn readfile [filename]
  (println (System/getProperty "user.dir"))
  (println "Arguments: " filename)
  (slurp filename))
```

And then I run this at REPL and I get the contents of the file

```
(require '[testpj.core :as h]) 
  (h/readfile file1.txt)
```

But when I change the above code to main and I try to give the file name at the 
  command line

```
lein run file1.txt



(defn -main [& args]
(println (System/getProperty "user.dir"))
(println "Arguments: " args)
(slurp args))
```

, I am getting the following error:

"java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot open <("file1.txt")> as an InputStream."

Can anyone help? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The argument vector for `-main` is `[& args]`, which means that `-main` accepts any number of arguments.  Inside the function, the var `args` will be bound to a list of the arguments passed to it, or `nil` if no arguments are given to the function.  So, to `slurp` the *first* argument passed to a function which takes multiple arguments:

```
(slurp (first args))
```

Comment: You say "the var `args`", but remember that "var" is a word with a specific meaning in Clojure, and function locals are a different thing. You could call it a binding, a local, or an argument.